# How to read log file from within pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job that runs a maven build. In the "post" section of the pipeline, I want to get the log file so that I can perform some failure analysis on it using some regexes. I have tried the following:

```
def logContent = Jenkins.getInstance()
        .getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME)
        .getBuildByNumber(
            Integer.parseInt(BUILD_NUMBER))
        .logFile.text
```

Error for the above code

> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins
>   getInstance

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLogFile()
```

Error for the above code

> Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getLogFile

From my research, when I encounter these, I should be able to go to the scriptApproval page and see a prompt to approve these scripts, but when I go to that page, there are no new prompts.

I've also tried loading the script in from a separate file and running it on a different node with no luck.

I'm not sure what else to try at this point, so that's why I'm here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm aware of the BFA tool, and I've tried manually triggering the analysis early, but in order to do that, I need to be able to access the log file, so I run into the same issue.

Comment: Is the sandbox enabled in the pipeline?

Comment: Yep. I have seen where other people from my organization have run different scripts from me that got rejected, and they were able to approve them from the scriptApproval page. Maybe there's something special about the specific scripts I'm trying to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipeline step `httpRequest` from [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
      stage('Build') {
          steps {
            echo 'Test fetch build log'
          }
          post {
            always {
              script {
                def logUrl = env.BUILD_URL + 'consoleText'

                def response = httpRequest(
                  url: logUrl,
                  authentication: '<credentialsId of jenkins user>', 
                  ignoreSslErrors: true
                )

                def log = response.content

                echo 'Build log: ' + log
              }
            }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

If your jenkins job can run on linux machine, you can use `curl` to archive same goal.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            environment {
                JENKINS_AUTH = credentials('< credentialsId of jenkins user')
            }
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
            }
            post {
                always {
                    script {
                        def logUrl = env.BUILD_URL + 'consoleText'
                        def cmd = 'curl -u ${JENKINS_AUTH} -k ' + logUrl

                        def log = sh(returnStdout: true, script: cmd).trim()

                        echo 'Build log: ' + 
                        echo log
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Above two approaches both require the credentials is `Username and password` format. More detail about what is it and how to add in Jenkins, please look at [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using user credentials? This is going into a github repo, and I would like to keep my credentials separate. Maybe there's an API call to get the credentials from the build itself?

Comment: It requires credentials Id, rather than the real username and password.  When you add username and password pair in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Credentials, you can given an name to this pair, the name called credentials Id. If you not given a name, Jenkins will generate a random string as the value for crendentails Id.  Therefor, the real username and password is stored on Jenkins, won't be on github.  Github just stores the crendentails id.

Comment: Ah I see, I will this a go and post afterwards, thanks!

Comment: If the job can alway run on linux machine, you can archive same goal via linux `curl [options] url` which get the response of a http request.

Comment: How do I get the authentication using curl? I tried using -H option and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible via the `RunWrapper` object that is made available. See https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46376 for a request to add this.
So the only options are:

- explicitly whitelisting the methods
- read the log via the URL as described in the other answer, but this requires either anonymous read access or using proper credentials.